# Orders showing on account overview but not on history

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I am currently working off a theme we have brought and styling, and it appears that a customers orders are showing when they log in and on the overview page, however when I click the link to the right to view all her orders they are not showing.

[image]

Thoughts welcomed.

Thanks

EDIT :

As per Rickys request i have copied over several XML files for various purposes.

I have had a search through the files and i cant see anything to do with the template mentioned to do with history in the customer.xml where i would believe it could be overridden. Please see my XML below for the customer.xml.

http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

Supported layout update handles (action):
- customer_account_index
- customer_address_index
- customer_address_view
- customer_account_login
- customer_account_logoutsuccess
- customer_account_create
- customer_account_forgotpassword
- customer_account_confirmation
- customer_account_edit

Supported layout update handles (special):
- default

-->

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title before_text" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><li/><a/></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer_links2">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /><title>My Account</title></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <!---<reference name="right">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
    </reference>-->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

```
<customer_account_logoutsuccess translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Logout Success</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="customer_logout" template="customer/logout.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_logoutsuccess>
```

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>

<customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
    <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
        <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_forgotpassword>

<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_changeforgotten>

<customer_account_confirmation>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Send confirmation link</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="accountConfirmation" template="customer/form/confirmation.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_confirmation>

<customer_account_edit translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Edit Form</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Edit Account Info</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/form_edit" name="customer_edit" template="customer/form/edit.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
      <action method="unsetChild"><name>left.permanent.callout</name></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addBodyClass"><class>customer-account</class></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <!--<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">-->
            <!--<action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>-->
            <!--<action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>-->
            <!--<action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>-->
        <!--</block>-->
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>

    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Dashboard</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_hello" name="customer_account_dashboard_hello" as="hello" template="customer/account/dashboard/hello.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top" />
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_newsletter" name="customer_account_dashboard_newsletter" as="newsletter" template="customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml"/>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard_address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>

</customer_account_index>
```

```
<customer_address_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Address Book</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/address_book" name="address_book" template="customer/address/book.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_address_index>
```

```
<customer_address_form translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Address Edit Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/address_edit" name="customer_address_edit" template="customer/address/edit.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_address_form>
```

Comment: Are no orders showing at all? e.g blank page?

Comment: Hi Ricky, yep no orders at all. They are showing on the main page itself as in the overview. The template being used is just the standard 2 col, so i cant see why that would have been effected.

Answer (score 0):

in `/app/design/frontend/[template name]/default/layout/` are there any theme specific .xml files?

You're looking for an override of `sales/order/history.phtml`. Removing it from the .xml will fall back to magento default - if that works, there's an issue with the themes code in `sales/order/history.phtml` (update your question with this code for me to diagnose)

Comment: Hi Ricky, I will update it now as per your request (please see above in 2)

Comment: Hi Ricky, I removed all the XMLs from the folder, and it still make no impact. :S

Comment: Hi Ricky, happy to post my history.phtml into here for you. However this is just will be a copy from the RWD as this folder is missing from my theme so it was using a fallback anyways

Comment: @KirstyMarks are there any extensions that may be over-riding the history area? E.g. order fulfilment extensions, payment gateways etc. If these have xml in the rwd theme, you'll need to copy those xmls to your new themes layout folder